# can't get a file size in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, filesize, python-3.8

I am a python newbie and learning from "automate boring stuff" book, so it says in the book the I can use os.path.getsize(path) to get a file size but when I run this code it gives an error, can you please explain why I am getting this?

```
import os

mypath = 'C:\\Users\\C2D\\Desktop\\Embedded system\\u1.PNG'
os.chdir(mypath)
print(os.path.getsize(mypath))
```

error is :
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\Users\C2D\Desktop\Embedded system\u1.PNG'

I am working on windows 8.1 and using python3.8 on pycharm

Comment: The error is happening in `os.chdir()`. `u1.PNG` is a file, the argument to `os.chdir()` has to be a directory.

Comment: Didn't the traceback of the error tell you that? Why did you think the problem was with getting the size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is failing because of the line `os.chdir(mypath)`.  You don't need to `chdir()`.

Assuming the path is correct and the file exists, it should work (print the file size) if you remove the `os.chdir()` statement.

Answer (score 3):

`mypath` is a file and not a folder.
With the command `os.chdir(mypath)` you are trying to change the folder - into an image.

It is generally very important, in which exact line an exception occurs. In this case it will be line 4.

To solve your problem: You can probably just delete this line.